# How were Egyptian riches distributed among the Israelites?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, mishkan-tabernacle

The Torah says that the Israelites donated a lot of their precious belongings to build the Mishkan (and the Golden Calf).  Where did they get these belongings?  The Torah says: From the Egyptians, on instruction from God:

> And the Lord said to Moses... Speak, please, in the ears of the people, and let them ask every man of his neighbor, and every woman of her neighbor, jewels of silver, and jewels of gold... [Ex. 11:1-2]

My question is:

(1) Did each Israelite take individual belongings from individual Egyptians, and they became his, with some ending up with more than others?

or

(2) Was everything that was taken from the Egyptians collected and divided among the Israelites in an equitable manner?

Comment: Seems like the 2nd possibility is the one that would require evidence.

Comment: Rashi shemos 15:22 seems to indicate that the money they got by the yam suf was whatever they each found for themselves, they took. Moshe had to forcibly get them to move on and stop gathering riches.

Comment: @Chatzkel -- Rashi references "Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 12:36", but Sefaria organizes the Mekhilta differently.  What does the Mekhilta say?

Comment: IIRC the collecting in Egypt was getting their own stuff back that the Egyptians stole. Still, the Egyptians ended up giving them even more and your question will apply to that

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Shimon_Ben_Yochai.12.36?lang=bi

Comment: Most of us have just read about this in books. You actually lived it@MauriceMizrahi. How did it go down?

Comment: @יהושעק -- I was forced out of Egypt with literally nothing and I am not about to get any of it back, let alone any "extras". :-)

Comment: Moshe was praised that he picked ayzmos yosef than bizas mitzraim, if it was equal split, it wouldnt be such a maila.

Answer (score 0):

On parshas ויקהל the chizkuni says that everyone asked from the Egyptians stuff that befit their status. (פסוקים כז-כח)

Comment: Just saw it today.